# With SoundCloud default audio widget can you set it to shuffle from JavaScript?

Tags: soundcloud, oembed

I am using the default SoundCloud audio widget to play a playlist and would like the songs to play in a random order.  I am using the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK oEmbed object (the iframe version).

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>  

SC.oEmbed("//soundcloud.com/buzzinfly",  { 
  auto_play: true,   
  start_track: random_start_track,  
  iframe: true,  
  maxwidth: 480,  
  enable_api: true,  
  randomize: true 
 },  
 document.getElementById("soundcloud_player"));
```

The documentation doesn't mention any randomize or shuffle attribute, but other undocumented attributes like start_track are supported with oembed.

```
//developers.soundcloud.com/docs/oembed#parameters
//developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget
```

Does any one know if there is an attribute to shuffle the song order in the default audio widget?

If not, is there is a way to capture events from the default SoundCloud widget, so I can play a random song after a song finish event?   Like you can with the custom player.

//developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player#events

```
$(document).bind('onPlayerTrackSwitch.scPlayer', function(event, track){  
  // goto random track   
});
```

Thanks

---

**Update**

Here is code am I using after getting gryzzly's help.

The next button works great.  I can skip thru random songs.  Unfortunately, when a track finishes playing, I hear the audio of two songs: the next song in the playlist and the random track that is skipped to in the FINISH event.

```
var widget = null;
var song_indexes = new Array();
var current_index = 0;

$(function() {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#soundcloud_player iframe');
    widget = SC.Widget(iframe);        
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        widget.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH);
        widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function() {        
            play_next_shuffled_song();
        });

        widget.getSounds(function(sounds) {
            create_shuffled_indexes(sounds.length);
            play_next_shuffled_song();
        });               
    });
    $("#button_sc_next").on("click", play_next_shuffled_song);
});

function play_next_shuffled_song() {
    current_index++;
    if (current_index >= song_indexes.length) {
        current_index = 0;
    }  
    var track_number = song_indexes[current_index];
    widget.skip(track_number);
}

function create_shuffled_indexes (num_songs) {
    for (var i=0;i<num_songs;i++) {
        song_indexes.push(i);
    }
    song_indexes = shuffle(song_indexes);
}

//+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
//@ http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle [v1.0]
function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your code and it seems to work fine for me! Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/unefut/2/edit

Comment: Problem happens if you set iframe src to http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=%2Fidontlikewords%2Ffavorites

Comment: http://jsbin.com/unefut/4/edit   Click to just before the end of a song.  Let it play out to the end. When the new random songs starts, so will the next song in the playlist.  If you press pause, it will just pause the random track.  The next song in the playlist still plays.  Maybe there is something up with playing favorites.  I tried changing the URL to likes (which is what they call favorites now), but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the documentation for Widget API [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget).

Pseudo code for this would be something like:

```
load widget
get widget sounds LENGTH /* say 5 */
create an ARRAY of that LENGTH and shuffle it /* to have something like [3, 1, 0, 2, 4] */
create function SKIP that will check if ARRAY still has any items in it (length is not 0) and skip player to array.pop() index /* pop will return the last item in the array and return its value */
attach event handler to FINISH events that will run SKIP function
run SKIP function first time yourself
```

If user skips with the “next” control in widget's UI the widget will
   just play next song in the list. You could perhaps detect that
   somehow and skip to another random track.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Using the Widget API, I was able to have a button skip to a random song.  Unfortunately if I have the FINISH event call the same skip function, a second song plays in the background.  It plays the next song in the playlist and the random song that is skipped to.