# SoundCloud embed widget, would like it to start on a random song each time

Tags: random, widget, embed, soundcloud, shuffle

On this page I see many features for the widget: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget

But I don't see anything about random or shuffle.  The way I have my widget on my website, the track listing is not displayed on purpose, so all that you can see is the play/pause button and the title.  Gives it a minimalist and really clean look.

But I'd like it to start on a random song each time someone visits/refreshes the site.  Is this possible?

Here is my code, just the standard embed:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="65" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F5346417&amp;color=579ce6&amp;auto_play=true&amp;show_artwork=false"></iframe>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [With SoundCloud default audio widget can you set it to shuffle from JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572253/with-soundcloud-default-audio-widget-can-you-set-it-to-shuffle-from-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've managed to do this using JavaScript and the JS Widget API. This provides the use of Method .skip() which I set to a random number between zero and the number of tracks in my playlist. This also invokes autostart.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Variable declaration
    var player = SC.Widget($('iframe.sc-widget')[0]);
    var randomVal;

    //player initialisation
    player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {

        randomSong(player);
        player.play();
    }); 

     //Set the random song
     function randomSong(player) {

        randomVal = Math.random() * 10;
        for(i = 0; i < randomVal; i++)
        {
            player.next();
        }
    }
});
```

It works perfectly for me with the Google Chrome browser.

I used this example as the main source for my [soundcloud player](https://codepen.io/nickcolley/pen/uoCIy).

I just added the random function as you can see in this comment.